# What is the probability that either of the two girls will be chosen to represent their school?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

> The chess clubs of two schools consist of, respectively, 8 and 9 players. Four members
>   from each club are randomly chosen to participate in a contest between two schools. The
>   chosen players from one team are then randomly paired with those from the other team,
>   and each pairing plays a game of chess. Suppose that Rebecca and her sister Elise are on
>   the chess clubs at different schools. What is the probability that either Rebecca or Elise will be chosen to represent her school?

Here is what I tried to do; Event A is probability that Rebbecca gets chosen to represent her school, which is $\frac{4}{8}$ and the same goes for event B, which probability that Elisa is chosen to represent her school is $\frac{4}{9}$. Now for the interception where both events occur at the same time is $\frac{4}{8}$*$\frac{4}{9}$.

$P(A\cup B)$ = $P(A) + P(B) - P(AB)$ = $\frac{4}{8}$ + $\frac{4}{9}$ - ($\frac{4}{8}$*$\frac{4}{9}$) = $\frac{13}{18}$

However, according to my book this is not the right answer and it should have been $\frac{1}{2}$ instead.

Could anyone provide some insight on this kind of them. And a clear way to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is probably the case is that when the question asked for the probability of "**either** Rebecca **or** Elise", it is intending the *exclusive or* case, where it is one or the other, *but not both*. This becomes:
$$
P(A \cap \bar{B}) \cup P(\bar{A} \cap B)
$$
Which would be:
$$
\left(\frac{4}{8}\cdot\frac{5}{9}\right) + \left(\frac{4}{8}\cdot\frac{4}{9}\right) = \frac{20}{72} + \frac{16}{72} = \frac{36}{72} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: Why is the complement of B $\frac{5}{9}$ and complement of A is $\frac{4}{8}$ ?

Comment: the complement of a fraction is determined by $1-$ the fraction if the fraction is less than 1 (proper fraction)

Comment: Because $A$ has $8$ people in her school and $B$ has $9$. If $P(A) = \frac{4}{8}$ then $P(\bar{A}) = 1 - P(A) = 1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$. Similarly, if $P(B) = \frac{4}{9}$ then $P(\bar{B}) = 1 - P(B) = 1-\frac{4}{9}=\frac{5}{9}$.

Comment: Wow!! I totally forgot about that. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: shoudl the second parenthesis have a $\frac{1}{2}$ for the complement of A ?

Comment: $\frac{4}{8} = \frac{1}{2}$ ;)